# How to create opening splash screen with Mosync

Tags: android, mobile, splash-screen, mosync

I'm learning [Mosync](http://www.mosync.com) (android,iphone,etc. development tool)
and I want to make Android application using HTML+Javascript

Anyone can give me explanation and sample
how to make splash screen with Mosync?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just started also ;).

What I found is description of HybridMoblet.cpp in which you can find how  moblet is working and showPage(url) which is used in main.cpp. Look: https://github.com/MoSync/MoSync/blob/master/libs/Wormhole/HybridMoblet.cpp

As I was playing a minute with this code in main.cpp (-> this is the file in your project where everything starts ;)) and I could for example change color of Screen before webview is loaded -> you must wait for NativeUI::WebViewListener::webViewContentLoading described here:
http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html/group___native_u_i_lib.html#gac528e65c1e50f2b7968837bd904de613

Hope this helps ;) Good luck

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and idea. I also found this example: 
https://github.com/MoSync/MoSync/blob/master/testPrograms/native_ui_lib/WebViewTest/Main.cpp

How to show image instead of loading text. Thanks.

Comment: Show Image: https://github.com/MoSync/MoSync/tree/master/testPrograms/native_ui_lib/ImageTest

Comment: Thanks, I've successfully display the image. But I am still confused how to combine it with WebView.

Comment: 1. show screen 2. show image 3. create webview 4. set WebView visible false 4. attach WebView to layout and call url loading 5. overwrite virtual void  webViewContentLoading(
   WebView* webView,
   const int webViewState)
  { //here add image hide and webview visible true 
  }                                                                                                   Let me know if it helps ;)